# My $(window).scroll is not responding (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need my scroll to tell me my scrollTop

So i have code kind of this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('Hi!');
$(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log('Scrolling...');
  var wScroll = ($(window).scrollTop());
  console.log(wScroll);
});
});
```

but cosnole is silent. She tell me Hi!, but she don't say Scrolling... anyway. I tried a lot. So now i am asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code,

See [jQuery.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/). Make sure that scrollbar is visible otherwise the scroll event will not fire.

Also try changing your **window listener** to the **div** if you want to listen to a **specific** div scrolling.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log('Scrolling...');
  var wScroll = ($(window).scrollTop());
  console.log(wScroll);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have **body{ height: 100% }** 
or i need something exactly like that

Comment: Okey, so the problem was that the body height was not defined correctly

Answer (score 0):

The script appears correct. However, I have this feeling that either you're not editing the correct file (it can happen), or you need to clear your cache as the browser is probably using a cached version of the file. Both Firefox and Chrome have an option to disable the cache when the dev tools are open. That way, you don't need to clear every time.

Comment: No! I solved the problem. The thing is that my scroll that prgrammed by JS never will work if JS dunno the height in pixels or something another. JS don't care about my % and smth like that BECAUSE JS is loading faster than DOM created EVEN if you did $(document).ready